# Rotation matrix R1 w.r.t to another matrix, say R2

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, triangulation, stereo-3d

I have two camera rotation matrices R1 and R2. Both of them are calculated w.r.t. a reference frame.

My ultimate goal is to perform stereo 3D triangulation using the corresponding features from these two images.

My question, given two rotation matrices R1 & R2 w.r.t some reference frame, how can I calculate the matrix 'R' which represents the rotation between first and second frame?

Thanks

Comment: These may be obvious, but I'd rather ask than make assumptions: 1) What exactly does R1 do? Does it transform the axes of the common reference frame to those of camera 1? Or is it something else? 2) What should R do? Should it convert the axes of frame1 to frame2? More importantly, what is the reference frame in which said axes should be expressed?

Comment: Given a reference frame, R1 is the rotation component of first camera w.r.t. the reference pt. Given: a point X in reference frame, it will be R1*X in the first camera frame. Similarly for R2. R should be rotation of 2nd camera with respect to the 1st camera. Refer to @user502144 's answer. That's what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If R1 is a rotation component of the first camera matrix and R2 - of the second, then the second camera frame is rotated by R2*inv(R1) with respect to the first camera frame. I.e, given a point X in a first frame, it will be R2*inv(R1)*X in the second frame.